# yii2 widgets are not installing via composer

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

[image]

Can't able to install widget using composer for yii2 framework

My composer look like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0"

},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
```

Comment: please add `composer.json` too

Comment: swiftmailer 6.0.2  requires php 7 your php version is 5

Comment: updated my answer please verify

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your constraint in the `composer.json` to the following

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
```

As according to the [**`DOCS`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/commit/5cd97193864b7444ba3d13b163caf3e65ee12cec)

> Note: `Version 2.1` of this extensions uses `Swiftmailer 6`, which
>   requires `PHP 7`. If you are using `PHP 5`, you have to use `version
>   2.0` of this extension, which uses `Swiftmailer 5`, which is compatible with `PHP 5.4` and higher.

Comment: This is incorrect - `~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0` allows to install `2.0.x` and it will be installed if environment does not support PHP 7. Changing constraints in this way does not really change anything, except worsening support for PHP7.

Comment: i dont quite get if i am wrong at mentioning the docs or changing the version to `2.0` from `"~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0"` @rob006

Comment: You're wrong in assumption that `~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0` will install Swiftmailer 6 on PHP5. This constraint allows to install `yii2-swiftmailer:2.0.x` and Composer is smart enough to not trying to install PHP7-only packages when it is run on PHP5. Changing constraint to `~2.0.0` is pointless in this case, because constraint is not the problem here. OP probably has `composer.lock` generated on PHP7 with Swiftmailer locked on 6.0.2.